# Как получить списк файлов, отсортированный по типу

Tags: c#, uwp

Пробую получить вот таким способом:

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, fileTypeFilter);

queryOptions.SortOrder.Clear();

SortEntry se = new SortEntry();
se.PropertyName = "System.ItemType";
se.AscendingOrder = false;            
queryOptions.SortOrder.Add(se);
```

.....

```
var queryResult = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> "System.ArgumentException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: На какой строчке?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем как оказалось, это не понятное, офф. ограничение

> If the folder being queried is not in a library or in the HomeGroup
>   folder, SortOrder only supports entries based on the
>   System.ItemNameDisplay (PKEY_ItemNameDisplay), System.Search.Rank
>   (PKEY_Search_Rank), or System.DateModified (PKEY_DateModified)
>   properties; SortOrder entries based on any other properties will
>   return E_INVALIDARG.